# Java stream : first element of the stream minus the sum of the rest of the stream

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I have an array of integer for example:

```
{ 30 , 2, 3, 4, 5}
```

Is it possible to create a lambda expression (using streams) for making the difference between the first element of the array ( in our example 30) and the sum of the rest of array `(2+3+4+5 = 13)` so the result would be 17?

Comment: You could calculate the sum of the last n-1 elements and subtract it from the first element (`inputArray[0]-IntStream.of(inputArray).skip(1).sum()`).

Comment: @Abhishek My problem is I did find a way to do it as a lambda expression in a single statement with chained call .

Comment: As a rule of thumb: whenever you give special treatment to a value at a specific index in the stream, your solution will become very awkward to express as a Stream job.

Comment: @Eran I tried your code and it works you can answer and I will choose your answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could calculate the sum of the last n-1 elements of the array and subtract it from the first element :

```
int result = inputArray[0] - IntStream.of(inputArray).skip(1).sum();
```

Comment: Cleaner and potentially more efficient: `Arrays.stream(inputArray, 1, inputArray.length)` instead of `IntStream.of(inputArray).skip(1)`…

Comment: @Holger Good suggestion. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

For your use case you could try:

```
IntStream.of(array).reduce( (left,right) -> left - right).getAsInt()
```

Comment: Not recommended as it violates the associativity constraint.